# When should I use JSDocs?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I know for functions with an `export` JSDocs are very useful, but there are other cases where I should use it?

Example, makes sense to add JSDocs for functions without `export`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use JSDocs as a stop-gap before having to switch to Typescript in order to provide better type ahead information for my IDE. Otherwise just use JSDocs when you need some extra information on whatever it is you are working on, be it attribution in the case of using someone else's code, or a better description that can be displayed from hovering over on an editor.